# Don't change alignment a div when change number of paragraph line's

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, compass-sass

I have a small issue whit div alignment.
In a paragraph, when increase number of line, alignment of div is too bad.

I think problem solved whit 'if' statement in sass, but I don't know what to do!!

Can anyone help me?

[image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F0At.png)

```
<div class="row content text-center">
            <div class="utility">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="thumbnail custom-thumbnial">
                        <img src="img/icon1.png">
                        <div class="caption"><p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="thumbnail custom-thumbnial">
                        <img src="img/icon2.png">
                        <div class="caption"><p>aaaaaaa</p></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="thumbnail custom-thumbnial">
                        <img src="img/icon3.png">
                        <div class="caption"><p>aaaaaaaa</p></div>
                    </div>
                </a>


            </div>
        </div>
```

=========
css:

```
.content {


background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#27AFFD, #1674A8); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#27AFFD, #1674A8); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#27AFFD, #1674A8); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#27AFFD, #1674A8); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  padding-right: 1%;
  height: 60vh;
  diaplay: flex;

  .custom-thumbnial {
    background: url(../img/icon-bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border: none;

    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
    .utility {
      position: relative;   
      }
    img {
      padding-top: 47%;
    }
    .caption {
      color: $color11;
      word-break:break-all; 
    }
  }}
```

Comment: Post the code you use

Comment: Update my question

Comment: I deleted my answer for now. You obviously have difficulties in understanding the solution I gave, so you need to update your question with a _working code snippet_, that reproduce the layout the pictures you showed me have. That will be the only way for me to help.